# How can I tell if my Picasa "legacy storage plan" is going to auto renew or not?

Tags: photos, picasa, google-drive, picasa-web

Around 11 months ago I paid Google (via Google Wallet) $5 for a year of 20GByte photo hosting on Picasa (or maybe I mean "Picasa Web"; I don't actually use the Picasa app).  I can't remember if there was an "auto renew" option presented at the time of payment, and if there was, whether I selected it.

Just looking into the what's going to happen when the year is up, [I see](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/) that the $5/year-for-20GByte is now considered a "[legacy plan](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39567&p=butter_old_storage)" and it seems likely google would prefer me to "upgrade" to an (IMHO extortionate) $2.49/**MONTH**-for-25GByte.  However, it appears I should be able to remain on the "legacy plan" *provided it's set to auto-renew*.

However, I don't see any information on the https://www.google.com/settings/storage/ (or on Google Wallet's "subscriptions" page, which seems to be a logical place it might appear) which helps me determine whether an auto renewal will be attempted or not.

Thanks for any relevant tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well google sent me a reminder email including this:

> This is a reminder that your one-year Google Storage plan is set to
>   automatically renew in 30 days.
>
> Since you purchased this plan before April 24, 2012 - the date we
>   updated our Google Storage plans - **and have set your plan to
>   automatically renew**, you can keep your current plan. Decide whether
>   you want to keep your current plan, purchase a new plan, or downgrade
>   to free storage...

(my bold) which answers my question.

Answer (score -1):

Don't give up your $5 a YEAR plan...you will NOT be able to go back to it if you want more storage space
in he future.  You will be forced to pay MONTHLY then

Comment: The asker already knows that; that's why he asked about auto-renewing.